# unknown package in google-chrome_stable 101.0.4951.64-1

Tags: apt, package-management, google-chrome

I'm trying to install google-chrome-stable:

```
sudo curl -sS -o - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add
sudo echo "deb https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y install google-chrome-stable
```

But I get the following error:

```
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
Need to get 90.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 302 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 fonts-liberation all 1:1.07.4-11 [822 kB]
Get:2 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 google-chrome-stable amd64 101.0.4951.64-1 [88.7 MB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libwayland-server0 amd64 1.18.0-1 [31.6 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libgbm1 amd64 21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1~20.04.2 [29.2 kB]
Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 udev amd64 245.4-4ubuntu3.16
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libu2f-udev all 1.1.10-1 [6,108 B]
Fetched 89.6 MB in 1s (89.9 MB/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/udev_245.4-4ubuntu3.16_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
```

It worked fine until May 10.
How can I fix it?

Edit:
I tried installing chromium:

```
%sh
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y install snapd
sudo snap install chromium
```

But got the same 404 error:

```
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
Need to get 36.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 158 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 udev amd64 245.4-4ubuntu3.16
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 apparmor amd64 2.13.3-7ubuntu5.1 [494 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 liblzo2-2 amd64 2.10-2 [50.8 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 squashfs-tools amd64 1:4.4-1ubuntu0.3 [117 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 snapd amd64 2.54.3+20.04.1ubuntu0.2 [34.3 MB]
Fetched 34.9 MB in 2s (17.7 MB/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/udev_245.4-4ubuntu3.16_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
```

The missing deb file is indeed missing from the ubuntu archive page (http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/)

Comment: May I suggest trying the official Chromium snap? It's not Chrome but is built from the open-source parts of Chrome: https://snapcraft.io/chromium

Comment: Or you can install it from the Chrome download page. https://www.google.com/chrome/ Make sure you download the one for "64-bit .deb (for Debian/Ubuntu)"

Comment: @ᅙᄉᅙ I tried your suggestion, and added the result to my post